# Issue with testing Tempfile in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, temporary-files

I have a block of code that creates Tempfiles

```
@tmp_file = Tempfile.new("filename")
```

I keep them closed after creation,

```
@tmp_file.close unless @tmp_file.closed?
```

When there is a need to add data to the temp files I open them and add data as below

```
   def add_row_to_file(row)
      @tmp_file.open
      @tmp_file.read
      @tmp_file.print(row.to_json + "\n")
    end
```

All is well, but for testing the same I have stubbed tempfile as below and is creating an error when the test case runs into `add_row_to_file(row)`

```
  buffers = {}

  Tempfile.stub(:new) do |file_name|
    buffer = StringIO.new
    buffers[file_name] = buffer
  end
```

Error message is :

```
Failure/Error: ]],
 NoMethodError:
   private method `open' called for #<StringIO:0x00000010b867c0>
```

I want to keep the temp files closed on creation as there is a max temp files open issue at OS level (I have to deal with uploading lot of tempfiles to S3)
but for testing I have a problem accessing the private method of StringIO.

Any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks.

I have a work around, which is to skip closing the StringIO when in test environment.

```
@tmp_file.close unless @tmp_file.closed? || Rails.env.test?
```

and update `add_row_to_file(row)` as below

```
   def add_row_to_file(row)
      @tmp_file.open unless Rails.env.test?
      @tmp_file.read unless Rails.env.test?
      @tmp_file.print(row.to_json + "\n")
    end
```

Comment: Why won’t you stub `Tempfile#open`?

Comment: strong doesn't have an `open` method (so you're actually calling Kernel#open)

Comment: I would agree with @mudasobwa. Don't stub `new` and don't test the behaviour of reading file, it is not your case. Test what's important here from your app point of view. If you need some input data, fake it in your test.

Comment: @mudasobwa if we stub `Tempfile#open` we will end in creating actual files when application encounters `@tmp_file = Tempfile.new("filename")` while running the test. As said I have a huge file creation, the test case will run for a longer time.

Comment: Is there any policy restricting stubbing both?

Comment: @mudasobwa when I tried stubbing the open it fails with the same error as Tempfile.new has StringIO.

Comment: @SantoshSindham I see you need some over approach to your tests, but to call the method `open` just use `@tmp_file.send(:open)`.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ when we do `@tmp_file.send(:open)` in `add_row_to_file(row)` while in test it fails as `@tmp_file.send(:open)
*** ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` in my case @tmp_file it self is `StringIO`

Comment: @SantoshSindham that ia because `#open` method require the "filename" too as a new.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ when @tmp_file is a Tempfile then `@tmp_file.send(:open)` works fine in fact it will error out as `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` if we pass a file name, however once opened as `@tmp_file.send(:open)` it is an instance of File, there on we will need to supply a file name. Same goes with StringIO.   `(using Test) #> k.class
=> File
(using Test) #> k = k.send(:open)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`   `(using Test) #> m.class
=> Tempfile
(using Test) #> m.send(:open, m)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
`

Comment: just use a selector: `args = [ :open ]; args << m if m.is_a? (File) ; k.send *args`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ k.send *args will error out as `private method `open' called for #<StringIO:0x00000010b867c0>` I thought of not closing the stream if it is a StringIO as created while in test. I will post my answer. Thanks for the valuable suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the work-around provided if we want 100% code coverage while in test we can try the below.

Do not close the stream if it is StringIO

```
@tmp_file.close unless @tmp_file.is_a?(StringIO)
```

so we dont need to open it while in test.

```
    def add_row_to_file(row)
      @tmp_file = File.open(@tmp_file, 'a+') unless @tmp_file.is_a?(StringIO)
      @tmp_file.print(row.to_json + "\n")
    end
```

In this way we can achieve the Tempfile testing without actually creating Files while in test environment and having 100% code coverage while in test.